# In R (rgl), how to print shadows of points in plot3d?

Tags: r, data-visualization, rgl

In R, using package `rgl`, I'd like to add the shadows of the points in `plot3d()`, just like in the image below.

[image: plot3d with shadows]

I've added the bottom grid using `grid3d()`, but still have no clue on how to add the shadows. If I plot the same points changing the 3rd axis value to its minimum value (-100 in the image), the plot area automatically increases, leaving a gap between the points and the grid. Is there a better way to do that?

I think it was obvious from the question, but here is a sample code:

```
library(rgl)
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100),
                 y=rnorm(100),
                 z=rnorm(100))
plot3d(df)
grid3d('z')
```

Comment: Please add a minimal example to your question.  I think `pca3d::pca3d(... show.shadows=T)` will suit your purpose, but you should add some data and the code that you have already so that this can be tested and confirmed

Comment: I often use `rgl` and I never saw any shadow (but I don't claim I know everything about `rgl`). A possible way is to do the shadow of your points manually, by projecting them on the plane and coloring them in gray. Maybe it's the method used by `pca3d`.

Comment: Agree with both comments but in the absence of a coded example it this question is off-topic for SO. SO is for coding questions and coding answers and at the moment this seems more a question about graphical display strategy.

Comment: @dww Example added. `pca3d` is extremely slow (to the point of being unusable). My table has 10,000 lines.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I thought about this kind of projection, and it kind of works, though the box increases to capture the shadows, and they are never exactly on the axis (like the grid is), but slightly over it.

Comment: @42- There's your example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea of setting `z` to the minimal value fails because `rgl` makes the bounding region slightly bigger.  But you can grab the `z` value from the grid, and use that.  You can also tell `rgl` not to expand the bounding box to include the new points.  This code does both things:

```
library(rgl)
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100),
                 y=rnorm(100),
                 z=rnorm(100))
plot3d(df)
id <- grid3d('z')                            # Get id values for grid
gridz <- rgl.attrib(id[1], "vertices")[1,3]  # Use the first z value
save <- par3d(ignoreExtent = TRUE)           # Ignore points for bbox
with(df, points3d(x, y, gridz, col = "gray"))# Plot the "shadows"
par3d(save)                                  # Restore bbox status
```

Here's what I get:

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I needed! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

there is now the convenience `show2d` function available to produce the desired 2D projections

```r
library(rgl)
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100),
                 y=rnorm(100),
                 z=rnorm(100))
plot3d(df)
grid3d('z')

show2d({
  par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
  plot(x = df$x, y = df$y, 
       col = "black")
})
```

[image]

Comment: It looks great! Thank you!